# JSF 2.0, Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.0 integration

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2

I am trying setup a web application with JSF 2.0 + Hibernate 4 and Spring 3.1. I am getting the following Exception when I test my Dao method.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'empDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.springHibernate.dao.EmpDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.springHibernate.test.TestEmployee.main(TestEmployee.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.springHibernate.dao.EmpDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1726)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1764)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:184)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:208)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.hibernate.validator.util.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.validator.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:521)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:119)
    ... 38 more
```

Below is my code

**Employee.java**

```
package com.springHibernate.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name="EmpID")
    private int empID;

    @Column(name="EmpName")
    private String empName;

    @Column(name="Email")
    private String email;

    public int getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    public void setEmpID(int empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

EmployeeDao.java

```
package com.springHibernate.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.springHibernate.model.Employee;

public interface EmpDao {

    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees();

}
```

**EmployeeDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.springHibernate.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.springHibernate.model.Employee;

@Repository("empDaoImpl")
public class EmpDaoImpl implements EmpDao{



    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(" from Employee").list();
    }


}
```

**EmpService.java**

```
package com.springHibernate.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.springHibernate.model.Employee;

public interface EmpService {

    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees();

}
```

EmpServiceImpl.java

```
package com.springHibernate.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.springHibernate.dao.EmpDao;
import com.springHibernate.model.Employee;


@Service("empServiceImpl")
public class EmpServiceImpl implements EmpService {
    @Autowired
    EmpDao empDao;

    public EmpDao getEmpDao() {
        return empDao;
    }

    public void setEmpDao(EmpDao empDao) {
        this.empDao = empDao;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return empDao.getAllEmployees();
    }

}
```

**EmployeeBean.java**

```
package com.springHibernate.managedBeans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.springHibernate.model.Employee;
import com.springHibernate.service.EmpService;

@ManagedBean(name = "empBean")
@RequestScoped
public class EmployeeBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{EmpServiceImpl}")
    EmpService empService;

    List<Employee> empList;

    private int empID;
    private String empName;
    private String email;

    public EmpService getEmpService() {
        return empService;
    }

    public void setEmpService(EmpService empService) {
        this.empService = empService;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmpList() {
        empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList.addAll(getEmpService().getAllEmployees());
        return empList;
    }

    public void setEmpList(List<Employee> empList) {
        this.empList = empList;
    }

    public int getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    public void setEmpID(int empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springHibernate.dao,com.springHibernate.managedBeans,com.springHibernate.service,com.springHibernate.model" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="Employee" class="com.springHibernate.model.Employee" />

    <bean id="EmpService" class="com.springHibernate.service.EmpServiceImpl">
        <property name="empDao" ref="EmpDao"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="EmpDao" class="com.springHibernate.dao.EmpDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="ASSET" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />



    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>SpringHibernate</display-name>

   <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

**Testclass**

```
package com.springHibernate.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.springHibernate.model.Employee;
import com.springHibernate.service.EmpService;

public class TestEmployee {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

         EmpService empService = (EmpService)ctx.getBean("empServiceImpl");

         List<Employee> l1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();

         l1 = empService.getAllEmployees();

         for (Employee e1 : l1)
             System.out.println("Employee Name:  "+e1.getEmpName());
     }

}
```

I am trying to use annotations. Slf4j is already present in lib folder. Please have a look at the code and help me to setup the project.

Comment: it seem you are missing some jars. You should use a dependency manager like maven for your dependencies. Please post your jars list.

Comment: Hi erencan, Thank you for the reply. Actually all jars are present in my lib folder. The problem is I forgot to add the property annotatedClasses to sessionFactory. So, Its not able to create the beans and dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the modified working applicationContext.xml. I forgot to add the property annotatedClasses to sessionFactory.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springHibernate" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="ASSET" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />

         <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.springHibernate.model.Employee</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: please mark your question as answered if this is the solution to the initial problem